# Do Holes move? ( Solid state electronics physics)

Tags: solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics

Actually the question that I'm stuck with is related to the holes i.e. the vacant space which occurs when the electron gets displace or move to another position. As holes is the vacant space with positive charge then how can they move when we study the forward and reverse bias characteristics, as it a space\position n how can it move.

Comment: Can bubbles move in a liquid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Holes are positive spaces which is created by absence of negative electron present there , so if the negative electron is moving throughout the substance then you can see the *relative* motion of how it moves , this is the same as how we model conventional current the movement of one electron in opposite direction can be the direction of flow of conventional current , here there are actually no positive charges moving!

The relative Movement of holes can also be explained by the same.

Comment: Oh exactly........a flying high five to you thankyou